# XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert below Source XML to Target XML using xslt.

In Source xml I have multiple ***`action`*** tags.
For every *`action/action_kind/code='pickup'`* there will be another *`action/action_kind/code='deliver'`*

In both `action` tags `orderId` is same.

I need to pick the *`from`* and *`to`* tags based on this  and I need to populate the Target XMLas shown below.

**Source XML**

```html
<section>
  
  <action>
    <action_kind>
      <code>pickup</code>
    </action_kind>
    <pickup>
      <orderId>11</orderId>
    </pickup>
    <name>NameOne</name>
    <address>AddressOne</address>
  </action>
 
  <action>
    <action_kind>
      <code>pickup</code>
    </action_kind>
    <pickup>
      <orderId>22</orderId>
    </pickup>
    <name>NameTwo</name>
    <address>AddressTwo</address>
  </action>
  
  <action>
    <action_kind>
      <code>deliver</code>
    </action_kind>
    <expected>
      <from>FirstOrderFro</from>
      <to>FirstOrderTo</to>
    </expected>
    <delivery>
      <orderId>11</orderId>
    </delivery>
  </action>
  
  <action>
    <action_kind>
      <code>deliver</code>
    </action_kind>
    <expected>
      <from>ScondOrderFro</from>
      <to>SecondOrderTo</to>
    </expected>
    <delivery>
      <orderId>22</orderId>
    </delivery>
  </action>
  
</section>
```

**Target XML**

```html
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <OrderId>11</OrderId>
    <Name>NameOne</Name>
    <Address>AddressOne</Address>
    <From>FirstOrderFro</From>
    <To>FirstOrderTo</To>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderId>22</OrderId>
    <Name>NameTwo</Name>
    <Address>AddressTwo</Address>
    <From>SecondOrderFro</From>
    <To>SecondOrderTo</To>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

Can some one give me the xslt solution which can convert the Source XML to Target XML?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, or to present your attempt to solve the problem yourself, or to explain where what you've tried so far is going wrong.

Comment: I'm looking for a xslt solution which will convert the Source XML to Target XML

Comment: We don't write code for you, we answer your questions. What is your question?

Comment: The question is when I use for-each on action tag I am getting 4 Order tags I want only 2 Order tags which will club 2 action tags based on orderId

Comment: Take a look at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html to see how Munchian grouping works. (It will work for both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.) If you still have issues, update your question with your XSLT and we'll point out what's wrong. (Hint: I'd use this key: `<xsl:key name="actionByOrderId" match="action" use="*/orderId"/>`)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Haley. I will try and update.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple ways, I found below way to get the expected out put.

```html
<xsl:template match="/">
   <Orders>
     <xsl:for-each select="/section/action">
       <xsl:variable name="PickupOrderId" select="pickup/orderId"/>
       <xsl:if test="action_kind/code='pickup'">
         <Order>
           <OrderId>
             <xsl:value-of select="pickup/orderId"/>
           </OrderId>
           <Name>
             <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
           </Name>
           <Address>
             <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
           </Address>
           <xsl:for-each select="/section/action">
             <xsl:if test="action_kind/code='deliver'">
               <xsl:if test="./delivery/orderId=$PickupOrderId">
                 <From>
                   <xsl:value-of select="expected/from"/>
                 </From>
                 <To>
                   <xsl:value-of select="expected/to"/>
                 </To>
               </xsl:if>
             </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
         </Order>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </Orders>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using Muenchian grouping like I mentioned in my comment.

**XML Input**

```
<section>
    <action>
        <action_kind>
            <code>pickup</code>
        </action_kind>
        <pickup>
            <orderId>11</orderId>
        </pickup>
        <name>NameOne</name>
        <address>AddressOne</address>
    </action>
    <action>
        <action_kind>
            <code>pickup</code>
        </action_kind>
        <pickup>
            <orderId>22</orderId>
        </pickup>
        <name>NameTwo</name>
        <address>AddressTwo</address>
    </action>
    <action>
        <action_kind>
            <code>deliver</code>
        </action_kind>
        <expected>
            <from>FirstOrderFro</from>
            <to>FirstOrderTo</to>
        </expected>
        <delivery>
            <orderId>11</orderId>
        </delivery>
    </action>
    <action>
        <action_kind>
            <code>deliver</code>
        </action_kind>
        <expected>
            <from>ScondOrderFro</from>
            <to>SecondOrderTo</to>
        </expected>
        <delivery>
            <orderId>22</orderId>
        </delivery>
    </action>
</section>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="actionByOrderId" match="action" use="*/orderId"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <Orders>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="action[count(.|key('actionByOrderId',*/orderId)[1])=1]">
        <Order>
          <OrderId><xsl:value-of select="*/orderId"/></OrderId>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('actionByOrderId',*/orderId)"/>          
        </Order>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Orders>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="action">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name|address|expected/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Orders>
   <Order>
      <OrderId>11</OrderId>
      <name>NameOne</name>
      <address>AddressOne</address>
      <from>FirstOrderFro</from>
      <to>FirstOrderTo</to>
   </Order>
   <Order>
      <OrderId>22</OrderId>
      <name>NameTwo</name>
      <address>AddressTwo</address>
      <from>ScondOrderFro</from>
      <to>SecondOrderTo</to>
   </Order>
</Orders>
```

Note: I left out the part capitalizing the first letter of the element names.